# Cannot connect to DB2 database after restoring an offline backup

Tags: restore, db2, db2-luw

This is for DB2 9.7 Enterprise Server Edition on AIX.

I had a full, offline backup taken of several databases within our instance in a performance environment.

I wanted to restore these databases to our integration environment.

I ran the command

```
db2 restore database database_name from 
/bkp/instance_name/OfflineBackups/RestorePoint/my_restore_point 
taken at 20120321103846 into database_name without prompting;
```

for each of my databases (modifying the database name and timestamp appropriately of course).

Each database restored successfully according to DB2. However, now when I wish to check if the database did indeed restore what I thought, I try to connect to a database and I get the error

```
    SQL1117N  A connection to or activation of database "database_name" cannot be made 
because of ROLL-FORWARD PENDING.  SQLSTATE=57019
```

I didn't have any in process transactions in the previous database because all connections were forced off and the database was down for an offline backup. What do I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer [here](http://www.dbforums.com/db2/1640530-restore-without-rolling-forward.html).

I needed to run the command

```
db2 rollforward db database_name to end of backup and complete;
```

This commits everything to the logs and places the database in a no longer pending state, thus allowing connection to it. I needed to do this for each database restored.

> **EDIT:** Found this nifty nugget while attending a [DB2NightShow](http://www.dbisoftware.com/db2nightshow/index.php) episode. With 9.7 FP2, they introduced a registry variable called
>   DB2_RESTORE_GRANT_ADMIN_AUTHORITY. This is handy if you are restoring
>   a backup from one instance to another, as it automatically grants
>   instance owner SECADM, DBADM, DATAACCESS, and ACCESSCTRL on the
>   databases restored. With 9.7 FP5, the setting is dynamic and does not
>   require bouncing of the instance. I realize my original question had
>   nothing to do with security, but it can be encountered and thought
>   that this would be a handy tidbit placed here.

---

> **EDIT #2:** I recently found out that if the backup is an offline backup based on an archival logged database, I could have included the
>   clause `WITHOUT ROLLING FORWARD` in my `RESTORE` command. This would
>   have taken the database out of roll forward pending state immediately
>   upon successful restore, which would mean that I would not have had to
>   then issue the `ROLLFORWARD DB` command.

Comment: excellent, thanks for contributing the answer you found

Answer (score -1):

If the backup type may be in Online backup.

Use Log path ("/db2logtarget")

Eg:-
db2 => rollforward db userdb to end of logs and complete overflow log path("/home/user/target")