# Is storing archive logs on local disk and backups on vendor storage possible?

Tags: backup, db2, logs

I am using DB2 9.7.

My `LOGARCHMETH1` is set to VENDOR library. Example:

```
LOGARCHMETH1=VENDOR:/usr/openv/netbackup/bin/nbdb2.sl64
```

Is it possible to call the following backup command:

```
db2 backup database EAIBDB2I online \
    load '/usr/openv/netbackup/bin/nbdb2.sl64' \
    without prompting
```

if I change `LOGARCHMETH1` to be on local disk and not on VENDOR library? How should `LOGARCHMETH1`be specified for that, and do I need other settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should be able to have backups and archived logs go to different places (ie, backups could go to your `VENDOR` tool and archived logs to disk).

To send archived logs to disk you can do one of two things:

The first would be to set `LOGARCHMETH1` to `DISK`:

```
db2 "update db cfg using LOGARCHMETH1 'DISK:/dbarch/dblogs'"
```

The second method would be to have two forms of archiving logs. You can leave `LOGARCHMETH1` to your `VENDOR` and set up `LOGARCHMETH2` to point to `DISK`.

```
db2 "update db cfg using LOGARCHMETH2 'DISK:/dbarch/dblogs'"
```

I've not played with two forms of log archiving before, but I know that it is available.

In our company we write our backups and archived logs to disk and then sometime after midnight we have IBM's Tivoli Storage Manager (TSM) come along and take a file system snapshot so it will have a copy of the backups and archived logs. So then we have a backup of our backups. We probably could have worked in `LOGARCHMETH2` in our company, but so far this has been simplest for us.

Just giving you ideas of what you can do. :)

Comment: Hi Chris thanks as always.  I don't get the point of LOGARCHMETH2 paramter. What is it for? If both LOGARCHMETH are different from OFF logs will be written in both locations? Am I right? OK that wasn't what I thoght. By your answer you said I could have on different devices backups and archive logs so that is clear for me. Or I MUST(!!!) have LOGARCHMETH2 set if I want backup on different location (device)? thank you

Comment: Backups and archived logs are separate. So LOGARCHMETH1 & 2 have nothing to do with taking backups (outside of if you have circular then you can't taken onlines). They only have to do with archiving transaction logs. If 1 is set to OFF, then you have circular logging. If 1 is set to something else you immediately have archival logging. 2 is optional. If set to OFF then it is ignored. If set to something else, then you have two modes of archival logging going on. (think of it as having a backup of your archived logs).

Comment: So you don't need LOGARCHMETH2 set. But it is there in case you want it. And again, setting LOGARCHMETH1 and LOGARCHMETH2 just tells DB2 where you want to archive off your transaction logs. It does not tell DB2 where you want to take backups to. The two are independent in that respect (and should be from a best practice perspective).

Comment: Hello Chris it is totally clear now. If I may my last (unfortunately very begginer's) question-- is the maximum size of archive logs determined or not? On example if I turn archive logging on 1st January can there be a risk that I get out of storage space on local disk???  What steps should I take to  prevent that I get out of storage if number of logs is just keep bigger and their number is also bigger and bigger? Thank you and sorry for this simple question

Comment: No problem! Us DB2 users stick together! The maximum size of archive logs is determined ultimately by the file system (or vendor system) that you choose to archive them to. The size is influence based on your LOGFILSIZ, LOGPRIMARY, and LOGSECOND parameters (ie, how big and how many logs you have), as well as your transaction volume. Unfortunately there is no magic bullet there either. You have to play with those settings to determine your optimal. I'll continue in my next comment.

Comment: Best thing to do is to estimate your archive size to start with and work with your system admins on that. For example, we put 5 GB aside for our transaction systems, but found we needed to bump it up to 10 GB. But that is due to the number of transactions and our log file sizes. Good news if the disk fills for the archive folder, DB2 will try to use the FAILARCHPATH. Pending that fails (and we dont' actually use that) DB2 falls back on keeping the log in the path to regular transaction logs.

Comment: As for how to help keep disk clean...I high recommend you look at my answer to your other question http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35261/db2-online-restore-but-without-roll-forward/35282#35282 This answer shows that the AUTO_DEL_REC_OBJ setting can be used (with other settings) to clean up archived logs, as well as backups. Not sure how it would behave with the backups with your vendor product, but I know it works with both backups stored to both disk and TSM. Hope that helps!

Comment: OK so archive logs size is calculated with this: LOGFILSIZ*LOGPRIMARY equals on example 2GB.

Comment: When 2GB is fulfilled. DB2 will try to use the FAILARCHPATH. I do not have this defined. If I do not set AUTO_DEL_REC_OBJ setting  what will happen? Will I get some error (out of space ) or DB2 will insert in archive logs new transations while previous will be deleted?

Comment: DB2 will just keep the archived log in the regular log path then and start filling up that space.

Comment: Oooouh OK. So it will start filling ACTIVE LOG PATH. For the worst scenario - what will happen if that location after some time is also full??? And also how is calculated size of ACTIVE LOGS  (similar to LOGFILSIZ*LOGPRIMARY for ARCHIVE LOGS)? Thank you

Comment: (LOGPRIMARY + LOGSECOND) * LOGFILSIZ = size of Active logs With archiving add in another LOGFILSIZ or so to be safe (as it has to copy the archived log first before it deletes it. And my guess is if you run out of disk in your ACTIVE LOG PATH, then you can't commit any more transactions, and so you run into trouble. But hopefully as a DBA you would catch this first before it happens and perform any clean up necessary.

Comment: Hi Chris how are you? I need one additional question: is the maximum size of archive logs also calculated on this way LOGFILSIZ*LOGPRIMARY when you are using TSM? thank you

Comment: Well, I don't use TSM (I use DISK and then have TSM backup from disk), but I would assume it is (LOGFILSIZ * LOGPRIMARY) + (LOGFILSIZ * LOGSECOND).

Comment: Hello Cris how are you? can I maybe ask you to help me with this topic? Thank you in advance http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59001/db2-archive-mode-on-what-values-to-set-logprimary-logsecond-logfilsiz